# Nestjs typesafe mongoose, model functions not asking for correct types (any)

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

Shema Interfaces

```js
export interface MyCat {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

export type Cat = MyCat & Document;

export const CatSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  color: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});
```

Dto that the function receives (note that it has no color property)

```js
export class CreateCatDto {
  @IsString()
  readonly name: string = 'Franco';
}
```

Function called, it gives no error on new Cat(cat), gives error on runtime on mongoose saying missing required attributes

```js
  constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') private readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {}

  async create(cat: CreateCatDto) {
    // typescript should give me an error here :(
    const createdCat = new this.catModel(cat);
    return await createdCat.save();
  }
```

My question is, how do I make the model functions understand what they need to receive correctly? As from what I can see they often accept the `any` type

Answer (score 0):

You can use Typegoose https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/
For typesafe modelling